# How to serialize a few times in Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows, serialization, deserialization

Hi I tried everything :D
I have problem when i try deserialize file.xml a few times in windows app. Thx for help :)
Windows 8 app
I have MainPage, when I have menu

1. Someone picks "show data"
2. it goes on "dataPage"
3. I deserialize plik.xml, and show data, app shows data, everthing is good
4. I back to MainPage, and again i want to show data from the same file, but now i Cant read nothing, i mean 'word's doesnt contain data

   ```
                 DESERIALIZATION
      StorageFile sessionFile;

       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<word>));
       words = new List<word>();

       try
       {
           if (await XMLModifier.IsFileExists(XMLModifier.wordsContainter, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder) == true)
           {
               sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(XMLModifier.wordsContainter, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
               IInputStream sessionInputStream = await sessionFile.OpenReadAsync();
               words = (List<word>)serializer.Deserialize(sessionInputStream.AsStreamForRead());
               sessionInputStream.Dispose();
           }
           else
           {
               string data = DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year;
               word w = new word("Base is empty", "Base is empty", data, 0, 0, 0);
               words.Add(w);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           ..............
       }
   ```

Comment: Is there an exception?

Comment: No. I make this serialization in <code>protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)</code>. Is it call always when i display SecondPage by <code>this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));</code> ?